# Prestapyt update product price

Tags: python, odoo, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, odoo-16

I have this method in python that tries to update the product price from Odoo ERP.

My method:

'''

```
def set_prestashop_price(self):
    prestashop_url = "https://myurl.com/api"
    prestashop_key = "KEY"

    prestashop = PrestaShopWebServiceDict(prestashop_url, prestashop_key)

    for template in self:
        response = prestashop.search('products', {'filter[reference]': template.default_code})
        if response:
            product_id = response[0]
            product_data = prestashop.get('products', product_id)

            product_data['product']['price'] = str(template.list_price)
            
            try:
                response = prestashop.edit('products', product_id, product_data['product'])
                template.message_post(body=f"Product template {template.default_code} updated on Prestashop")
            except Exception as e:
                template.message_post(body=f"Failed to update product template {template.default_code} on Prestashop. Error: {str(e)}")
        else:
            template.message_post(body=f"No product found on Prestashop for {template.default_code}")
```

'''

When running the method it gives an error like this and i cant find any working solution for it.

Failed to update product template PROCUT1 on Prestashop. Error: 'Unsupported parameters: delivery_out_stock, unit_price_ratio, ecotax, low_stock_threshold, manufacturer_name, condition, indexed, low_stock_alert, available_now, meta_description, id_category_default, type, id_default_image, height, name, show_condition, price, delivery_in_stock, meta_keywords, active, customizable, id_tax_rules_group, on_sale, state, text_fields, cache_has_attachments, available_date, id_shop_default, upc, advanced_stock_management, isbn, date_add, minimal_quantity, visibility, pack_stock_type, online_only, supplier_reference, available_later, is_virtual, id_manufacturer, cache_default_attribute, weight, product_type, uploadable_files, quantity_discount, id_supplier, link_rewrite, reference, additional_delivery_times, unity, description, ean13, redirect_type, wholesale_price, associations, additional_shipping_cost, date_upd, meta_title, cache_is_pack, width, id_default_combination, id_type_redirected, mpn, quantity, depth, show_price, new, available_for_order, location, description_short, position_in_category, id'

Answer (score 0):

When trying to update the product data in PrestaShop using your prestashop.edit method, There are unsupported parameters being passed : delivery_out_stock, unit_price_ratio, ecotax, low_stock_threshold, manufacturer_name, condition, indexed, low_stock_alert, available_now, meta_description, ...(see your traceback message)

To resolve this issue, you need to modify the product_data dictionary to remove these unsupported parameters before passing it to the prestashop.edit method:

```py
def set_prestashop_price(self):
    prestashop_url = "https://myurl.com/api"
    prestashop_key = "KEY"

    prestashop = PrestaShopWebServiceDict(prestashop_url, prestashop_key)

    for template in self:
        response = prestashop.search('products', {'filter[reference]': template.default_code})
        if response:
            product_id = response[0]
            product_data = prestashop.get('products', product_id)

            # Remove unsupported parameters
            product_data['product'].pop('delivery_out_stock', None)
            product_data['product'].pop('unit_price_ratio', None)
            product_data['product'].pop('ecotax', None)
            # Remove other unsupported parameters...

            product_data['product']['price'] = str(template.list_price)

            try:
                response = prestashop.edit('products', product_id, product_data['product'])
                template.message_post(body=f"Product template {template.default_code} updated on Prestashop")
            except Exception as e:
                template.message_post(body=f"Failed to update product template {template.default_code} on Prestashop. Error: {str(e)}")
        else:
            template.message_post(body=f"No product found on Prestashop for {template.default_code}")
```

Or maybe, your have passed the wrong name for the prestashop template.